# css tree list correction

Tags: css, file, list, tree

I managed to create **tree list of directory** and have problems.

Problems:

1. <del>Sub-folders are not in same column as sub-files.</del>
2. <del>Lines of sub-folders are on last spot of column.</del>

[image: preview]

How to fix it ?

**PHP:**

```
  function ListFolder($path) {
        //using the opendir function
        $dir_handle = @opendir($path) or die("Unable to open $path");

        //Leave only the lastest folder name
        $dirname = end(explode("/", $path));

        echo '<ul>';

        //display the target folder.
        echo '<li><a href="'.$dirname.'" class="folder">'.$dirname.'</a>';
        echo '<ul>';
        while (false !== ($file = readdir($dir_handle))) {
            if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
                if (is_dir($path . "/" . $file)) {
                    //Display a list of sub folders.
                    ListFolder($path . "/" . $file);
                } else {
                    //Display a list of files.
                    echo '<li><a href="'.$file.'">'.$file.'</a></li>';
                }
            }
        }
        echo "</ul>";
        echo "</li>";

        echo "</ul>";

        //closing the directory
        closedir($dir_handle);
    }

    ListFolder("./files");
```

---

Here are lines

**CSS:**

```
ul,
ul ul {
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

ul ul {
    margin-left:10px;
    background:transparent url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAAKAQMAAABPHKYJAAAAA1BMVEWIiIhYZW6zAAAACXBIWXMAAAsTAAALEwEAmpwYAAAAB3RJTUUH1ggGExMZBky19AAAAAtJREFUCNdjYMAEAAAUAAHlhrBKAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC') repeat-y 0 100%;
}

ul li {
    margin:0;
    padding:0 12px;
    font-size:14px;
    line-height:20px;
    color:#369;
    font-weight:bold;
}

ul ul li {
    background:transparent url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAgAAAAUAQMAAACK1e4oAAAABlBMVEUAAwCIiIgd2JB2AAAAAXRSTlMAQObYZgAAAAlwSFlzAAALEwAACxMBAJqcGAAAAAd0SU1FB9YIBhQIJYVaFGwAAAARSURBVAjXY2hgQIf/GTDFGgDSkwqATqpCHAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==') no-repeat 0 0;
}

ul ul li.last,
ul ul li:last-child {
    background:white url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAgAAAAUAQMAAACK1e4oAAAABlBMVEUAAwCIiIgd2JB2AAAAAXRSTlMAQObYZgAAAAlwSFlzAAALEwAACxMBAJqcGAAAAAd0SU1FB9YIBhQIIhs+gc8AAAAQSURBVAjXY2hgQIf/GbAAAKCTBYBUjWvCAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC') no-repeat 0 100%;
background-position:left top;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="test" class="folder">test</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="aaa.txt">aaa.txt</a></li>
            <li><a href="bbb.txt">bbb.txt</a></li>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="subfolder" class="folder">subfolder</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="1.txt">1.txt</a></li>
                        <li><a href="2.txt">2.txt</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <li><a href="test.txt">test.txt</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Throw up the actual html the php spits out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One  tag was in loop so it repeat it self. Just needed to use it once.

Usage of php script:

```
echo "<ul>";
ListFolder("files");
echo "</ul>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `background-position:left top;` to line 29 of your `list.css` file.

[image: Screenshot with CSS change]

Comment: that resolve lines are at top, but still, sub-folders are not in same column as sub-files